# Can't get Mention to work, Ment.io

Tags: angularjs, mention

Guys i'm trying to get ment.io to work in textarea
Mentio by Jeff-collins
http://jeff-collins.github.io/ment.io/#/examples

```
 <textarea placeholder="start with @j" ng-model="myval"
class="form-control" mentio mentio-typed-text="typedTerm" 
mentio-items="people | filter:label:typedTerm"></textarea>
```

Am i require to use  `<mention-menu>` ??

Here's my [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jQ4O8u?p=info)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That took a while.....Needed to inject `mentio` in the app. I could not reproduce this in plunker. I used [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxcache/z2x6eac2/)

`angular.module('myApp', ['mentio']).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {`

Comment: My plunker was messed up with all bootstrap references.

Thanks for help.